# Hibernate Unidirectional One-to-One annotation mapping

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

How to use One-to-One mapping to do lazy load the Adress if studentId exist in Address table.

- Student is the Parent table
- Address the child table
- Not all student will have Address. If they do then based studentId from  address table do lazy Load.

[image]

I tried mapping but when try to ftch only student, i ended up with the below exception

```
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.abcCompany.AddressVO. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1070)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:989)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:716)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:502)
...
```

According to the Exception I can say, it is trying to map the Address with with addressId instead of studentId. So I tried this in Student Entity bean

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "student_Id")
private AddressVO address;
```

PS: Is this is possible to have bidrectional mapping too to get the Student from address by StudentId of address table.

Comment: You have in Student the student_id as String, in Address what type is student_id? It seems that you have student_id as Integer in Address class. You need to have the same data type in both student_id parameters

Comment: @mvlaicevich Student_Id is of type CHAR(36) in address table also.

Comment: But in your db that value is an integer, is that right? If this is right you need to change in Java from String to Integer